# Using IF In SQL Statement

Tags: sql

How can I create an sql statement based on a condition?

```
select Name, Address, Flag from Employees
If Flag = 'Y' then 
join Customers 
on id=id
else
join Clients
on id=id
```

For each record returned I want to either join to the Customers or the Clients table for additional information

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two different select queries and combine the result with `Union all`

```
SELECT NAME,
       Address,
       Flag
FROM   Employees e
       JOIN Customers c
         ON e.id = c.id
            AND e.Flag = 'Y'
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME,
       Address,
       Flag
FROM   Employees e
       JOIN Clients c
         ON e.id = c.id
            AND (e.Flag IS NULL OR e.Flag <> 'Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT e.Name,
       e.Address,
       e.Flag,
       CASE
         WHEN e.flag = 'Y'
           THEN c.some_column
         ELSE l.other_column
       END AS additional_info
FROM   Employees e
       LEFT JOIN Customers c
         ON e.id = c.employee_id
            AND e.flag = 'Y'
       LEFT JOIN Clients l
         ON e.id = l.employee_id
            AND e.flag = 'N'
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2965/1)** demo